# One page scroll и изменением URL

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Есть такой вот [интересный сайт](http://www.legworkstudio.com/) . На нем реализовано скорей всего onepageScroll . Когда листаем вниз открывается блок но у него свой url? как это реализовавается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Первая строка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) меняет url без перезагрузки страницы.
Вторая меняет title.

```
window.history.pushState('state', 'title', '/new-url');
document.title = 'new title'
```

Comment: ну менять это хорошо, только если я передаю например напрямую по ссылки то мне откроется именно этот блок

Comment: @duddeniska `$(document).ready` узнать ссылку через `window.location.href` и прыгнуть на нужный анкор или показать нужный контент